# Why is the court scene interrupted by the discussion between King, Frank and the Investigator when it makes the chronology harder to understand?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-irishman

In *The Irishman* (2019), In the court, the Prosecutor questions a man:

> PROSECUTOR: Did you make this statement  to the grand jury?  I'll read it for you. "Brennan came to me and said words  to  the effect he's gonna go ahead..."

Then scene cuts to the room where where Frank discusses with the Investigator and King while Big Eddie spies on them:

> KING: He's got a restaurant. Did you look into violations?
>
> INVESTIGATOR: Yeah. I'd rather stick with the women. They're more approachable.

Then cuts back to court scene:

> PROSECUTOR: came to me and said words to the effect he's gonna go ahead   and set up a company to lease trucks. But later, he called me on the phone  and said quote, "I gotta change the deal 'cause I gotta cut Hoffa in on the deal." Is that accurate, sir?

I didn’t understand the chronology of the scenes properly because they were non-linear.

Why is the court scene interrupted by the discussion between King, Frank and the Investigator when it makes the chronology harder to understand?